# The plugin generated 3265 characters of unexpected output

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to built fancybox plugins.I added all js and css file to my php file and add one image to it ,but I found this error.

> The plugins generated 3265 characters of unexpected output during activation.
>
> If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugins.

Comment: You probably have a bug. You should debug your code. Without knowing what you did and without seeing code, it is impossible to sanely answer this. Check my question above ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This type of message only because of your plugin having some php code mistake or you use some function name which is in infinite loop so try by using `var_dump('function name');` and after that `die;` to one by one each function.

You will surely find your bug.

Remember, bug is always small, but it's a big headache.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program containing extra white space after the `<?php .. ?>`
Please avoid that if any